# Open a project in Xcode without .xcodeproj

Tags: xcode

I would like to open an `Xcode` project , a source file, but when I download it, there is no `.xcodeproj` file, but all the rest of the files (controllers,delegates,etc).

The file was downloaded from here : ( I know..the law and all that, but its a professional question)

http://popcorn-time.to/source.html